# Twitter Login does not work if Twitter app is not installed in device

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-login

*This may be the most asked question on SO, but i am still unable to fix my problem.* 
I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325861/login-with-twitter-failure), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44546074/2541348) and many others, but the problem is still there.

If twitter app is installed on user's device, everything works fine, but if its not there i get the following error message.

> Invalid json: Callback URL not approved for this client application.
>   Approved callback URLs can be adjusted in your application
>   settings
>       com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING
>   at line 1 column 1 path $
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but
>   was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
>
> com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException: HTTP request
>   failed, Status: 403
>           at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback.onResponse(Callback.java:42)

I defined `https://www.google.com` as a callback URL, and following is my implementation.

```
//Activity Class

 Twitter.initialize(this);

 button.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {

                TwitterSession session = TwitterCore.getInstance().getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
                TwitterAuthToken authToken = session.getAuthToken();
                String token = authToken.token;
                String secret = authToken.secret;

                login(session);

            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                Log.d("Failure", "failure");
            }
        });
```

**Strings.xml**

```
   <string name="com.twitter.sdk.android.CONSUMER_KEY">---</string>
   <string name="com.twitter.sdk.android.CONSUMER_SECRET">---</string>
```

**Gradle**

```
compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.1.1'
```

*EDIT*

I have also tried `twittersdk://` and `twitterkit-consumer-key://` as callback Url

Comment: I think you are looking for a solution guide like this [androidhive](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-twitter-oauth-connect-tutorial/). I hope this blog will help you.

Comment: Have you checked this: https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-android/issues/135

Answer (score 5):

Refer this link [here](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-android/issues/108#issuecomment-397499851).

We need to set twittersdk:// inside callback URL as described in link like below.

1. go to your twitter app setting https://apps.twitter.com/ >> Tab
   settings >> Fill this text "twittersdk://" to your callback URL
   field( I found it in lib class)
2. Save your update
3. check out your app again.

It worked just by setting twittersdk:// as one callback URL, without appending anything.

Comment: It should work as @fightingCoder said, but if you look at the source code here (https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-android/blob/d71efe38404b5233e312f2531efbf72e5ce5d7bc/twitter-core/src/main/java/com/twitter/sdk/android/core/internal/oauth/OAuth1aService.java) you can see that the default CALLBACK_URL is "twittersdk://callback" maybe you can give it a try.

Comment: @fightingCoder I am already using `twittersdk://` as a `callback URL`, and facing the same issue.

Comment: @Legion : When i tried `twittersdk://callback`, it gives me `Not a valid URL` error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try FireBase Ui auth sdk , i think it will be the best solution for you ,
   read documents https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui